# Limit events in calendar:cal and disable occurrences

Tags: solspace, solspace-calendar

How do i limit the event to like 3 and how do i disable the occurrences? I just want to list main events rather than listing one event with multiple occurrences.

```
{exp:calendar:cal date_range_start="today" pad_short_weeks="n" dynamic="off" date_range_start="today" date_range_end="+5 days" show_recurrences="no"}
                   {display_each_day}
                <li>

                {events}
                <div class="box">

                    <div class="img">
                        <a href="{path='events/event'}/{event_id}/{if event_recurs}{event_start_date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/{/if}">


                        </a>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <h3>
                            <a href="{path='events/event'}/{event_id}/{if event_recurs}{event_start_date format="%Y/%m/%d"}/{/if}">{event_title}</a>
                        </h3>
                        <div>{if event_summary  != ""} {exp:ce_str:ing truncate="100"}{event_summary}{/exp:ce_str:ing}{/if} </div>
                        <div class="dse">


                            <span>{event_calendar_title}</span> |

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                {/events}


            </li>

  {/display_each_day}
{/exp:calendar:cal}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using [Calendar 1.x for EE 2.x](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1), you would use the [Calendar:Events](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1/events/) template tag instead of [Calendar:Cal](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1/cal/) template tag.

Calendar:Cal will show all events and their recurrences in chronological order, while Calendar:Events will show only the "parent" event entries (with no recurrences). See this overview diagram:

[image]

For more information, check out the [Getting Started documentation](https://solspace.com/legacy_docs/calendar-1/getting_started/). :)